# Can I use DirectX's DirectDraw to overwrite any pixel from any application?

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, directdraw

I would like to do some real-time image(?)/video(?)/screen(?) processing to everything the user sees. I am not very familiar with DirectX, so I am unsure if DirectDraw (recommended by chatGPT) allows me to do so by manipulating the screen buffer.

Are there any resources/articles I could refer to for more info on how to do this?

Does DirectX offer this functionality?

I have tried using winAPI's `SetPixel` (doesn't work due to other apps drawing on top) and layered windows, but I'm not a big fan of it. I need something that allows me to read and write to all the pixels that the user sees.

Comment: DirectDraw is the old thing you don't want to invest in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directdraw/directdraw). GDI's SetPixel would be slow as a dog for "real-time XXX processing". DirectX/DXGI/Direct2D/Shaders are what you're looking for, but you need to be more specific and/or do a little search by yourself. Google for "directx image processing" for example

Comment: You could try to draw the pixels in the draw the pixels and then have it "flipped" or "swapped" and sent to the screen on a refresh signal. You could start from the Doc:[Work with DirectX device resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dgetstarted/work-with-dxgi)

Comment: @SimonMourier are you suggesting that I take all the pixels on the screen, treat it as an image and do my processing on that, then render this to the screen? Do I have to do it in a window, or can I just write it to the screen buffer?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT No, sorry. The only "solution" I found was a really old website with partially working code. Let me know if you still need it and I'll try to find it for you.